# Ubuntu 14.04 black screen

Tags: 14.04, boot

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, when I started my pc today, it shows a black screen and then nothing, on safe mode, in /var/log/boot.log I have 2 fails :

```
*Starting Track if upstart is running in a container [fail]
*Starting rpcsec_gss daemon [fail]
```

How to solve it please ?

Comment: What happens if you boot with upstart?

Comment: Thanks anonymous2 for your answer, please how to do this upstart boot ? thanks

Comment: Please need help for this problem.

Comment: Looks like you solved this.  Sorry I couldn't answer sooner.  For future reference, upstart is usually in the advaced options for Ubuntu in the Grub.  I'm realising, though, that that may be an added feature in 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, by uninstalling ldap client.